# nested forloop with arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested

Given an array of Strings:

```
    String[] arrays = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N"};
```

I was able to make the pattern:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 6; j++)
        { 
            System.out.print(" " + arrays[j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I understand how my nested forloop works as i = 0 and j = 0, j will print all the array index letters to 6.
This code currently creates the format of a square:

```
     A B C D E F G
     A B C D E F G
     A B C D E F G
     A B C D E F G
     A B C D E F G
     A B C D E F G
```

But what i want is it to continue where it left off rather than repeat from previous, I know that I need a if statement somewhere in the nested for loop, but not sure what is contained in the if statement or how it looks like.
What I want:

```
     A B C D E F G
     H I J K L M N
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just have one loop going from the start of your array to the end of it. Then every seven characters print out a new line.

Comment: You can keep track of how many characters you've printed in the current line using another variable. Make sure you reset the variable correctly to zero after you've printed seven characters.

Comment: If it wasn't totally clear from my answer, you definitely don't need a nested for loop. You can just do this using a single loop.

Comment: David I understand where youre coming from I'm currently making the changes ill get back to you in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a nested `for` loop, you can test if the current index modulo half the `array.length` is `0` (that is if the remainder from division is `0`); if it is print a new line. Something like,

```
String[] arrays = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", 
                    "J", "K", "L", "M", "N" };
int half = arrays.length / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%s ", arrays[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % half == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
A B C D E F G 
H I J K L M N
```

Comment: I'm sorry elliot I wasnt clear enough on my question, the thing is that this is just a little test and the array is actually around 50 letters long and I want it to move down a row every 6 letters

Comment: I think you just have to write 7 instead of half and then this is the best answer so far

Answer (score 1):

you can make another variable to count the total iterations like this:

```
String[][] array = new String[2][7];
int indexKeeper = 0;
String[] arrays = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N"};
for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<7; j++) {
        array[i][j] = arrays[indexKeeper];
        indexKeeper ++;
        System.out.print(array[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

here is the output

```
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int j = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
{
    j++;
    System.out.print(" " + arrays[i]);
    if (j == 6)
    {
        System.out.println();
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while` instead of `for` loop like this

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String[] arrays = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N"};
    int i = 0, j = -1;
    while(i < arrays.length) {
        System.out.print(" " + arrays[i]);
        i++;
        j++;
        if(j == 6) {
            System.out.println();
            j = -1;
        } 
    }
}
```